# I get this error 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0086B000

Tags: c

I tired the same code on https://repl.it/languages/c and i get no errors but when i paste the same code on **Visual Studio 2017** I get this error regarding:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char input[100];
int calc();
int main() {
    printf("Type \"help\" or enter a mathematical expression\n");
    calc();
}
int calc() {
    printf("Calc:\\> ");
    scanf_s("%s", input);
    if (strcmp(input, "help") == 0) {
        printf("Help is on the way\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Answer:\\> %s\n", input);
    }
    calc();
    return 0;
}
```

But I get this error when i run it:

```
Exception thrown at 0x50FFD4EC (ucrtbased.dll) in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0086B000.
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019

Comment: Now the input is missing.

Comment: @melpomene input anything and this error will pop up without printing to console.

Comment: Oh, that probably happens because you're not passing enough arguments to `scanf_s`.

Answer (score 4):

Problem 1:

You are calling `calc()` recursively without a base case. This means that you will inevitably cause the stack to overflow when you call that function.

Solution:
Remove the recursive call to `calc()` in `calc()`.

Problem 2:

`scanf_s` requires that the string argument satisfying a `%s` format specifier comes immediately before an integer variable giving the length of the buffer. See its documentation on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(STDIO%2Fscanf_s);k(scanf_s);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019).

Solution: pass the length of the string as well:

```
scanf_s("%s", input, 100);
```

Side note: checking the return value of `scanf`-family functions is usually a good idea.

Comment: thanks man i didn't get error but i need that **calc()** to be recalled or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: @Bipin You should have it called in a while loop in `main` with an exit condition (like type `"exit"` to exit)